# BindingProperty is null in handler method called by ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In a Razor page I want to change the data of an entity. The data is loaded in OnGet and saved in OnPost. The data that is loaded in OnGet is saved to a property called `Person`. At a later time I can simply retrieve them in OnPost (it's the identical object).

However, if I use a handler called by an Ajax call, the property object is initialized (integer properties are 0, object properties are zero) but it is not the original object anymore.

What do I have to do so that the original object is also available in the handler called by the Ajax call?

I already tried to use [BindProperty] attribute and to use a hidden input in the razor page. Or to access `ViewData.Model` But is does not work. `Person` and other data of the model is still kind of null.

Ajax-Call:

```
function addEntitlement() {
        var vacationEntitlement = {};
        vacationEntitlement["Year"] = $('#newEntitlementYear').val();
        vacationEntitlement["Days"] = $('#newEntitlementDays').val();
        vacationEntitlement["PersonID"] = $('#hiddenPersonID').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./Edit?handler=AddEntitlement",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(vacationEntitlement)
        }).fail(function () {
            alert('error');
        }).done(function () {
        });
    }
```

PageModel:

```
    public IActionResult OnGet(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        Person = _unitOfWork.PersonRepository.GetByID(id);

        if (Person == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Page();
    }

    public JsonResult OnPostAddEntitlement([FromBody] VacationEntitlement vacationEntitlement)
    {
      ///Tried to acces Person or ViewData.Model.Person here.
      ///But Person is just intialized but does not contain the expected data.
    }
```

Comment: you mean you want the instance of `Person` from **OnGet** to be access in **OnPostAddEntitlement**?

Comment: Yep :) The `Person` is accessable in **OnGet** and in **OnPost** at the moment. But not in **OnPostAdd** but it should be.

Comment: That's not how things work. HTTP is a stateless protocol, so each request is as if it's the first time the client has ever interacted with the server. If you want some data to stick around, you need to create a session and save it there. That could be via `Session` or `TempData`. `TempData` is just a specialized form of `Session` that removes values after they're accessed, whereas normal session state would persist for the life of the session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `TempData` it allows you to pass data from one action to another action

```
Person = _unitOfWork.PersonRepository.GetByID(id);
TempData["Person"] = Person
```

then

```
public JsonResult OnPostAddEntitlement([FromBody] VacationEntitlement vacationEntitlement)
{
   if(TempData.ContainsKey("Person")) {
     var person = TempData["Person"] as Person; /* (as Person} I just assume the class name is Person */
     // place your logic here
   }
}
```

and also make sure to properly setup your TempData configuration
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#tempdata

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: Still null for me

Comment: Ok, found why it was null. You need to be [GDPR compliant](https://andrewlock.net/session-state-gdpr-and-non-essential-cookies/).